# Matlab - Concatenate strings with wildcard

Tags: matlab

I have two variables, A and B, which have a variable between them that creates a file name. e.g.

```
A*B.mat where *  %// can be any number of digits
```

Obviously dir A*B.mat does not work, but I haven't the faintest on how to actually make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this: concatenate the contents of `A` and `B` with the string `'*'` in between and `'.mat'` at the end:

```
dir( [A '*' B '.mat'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf`

```
dir( sprintf('%s*%s.mat', A, B ) );
```